# Where is my bandwidth?

Tags: monitoring, bandwidth

We've got a DSL line rated at 7Mbps.  The best speed test results are little over 4Mbps.  After replacing our modem, and spending hours on the phone with Verizon, they say that 4Mbps is within acceptable range.

The modem, configured as a bridge, gives its connection status: downstream rate: 7611Kbps, upstream rate: 863Kbps.

DSL goes into our Cisco ASA 5510, using Netflow into PRTG to monitor bandwidth.

We've got 4 virtualized servers running Datacenter R2 2008: Exchange, domain controller, AV and WSUS.  We average 15 users, some stream music, but no P2P.  PRTG shows nothing unusual going on, just that our total speed often remains below 500Kbps.

We've had this DSL line for years, and it was never this slow.

Is our ISP just failing us?  The confusing thing for me is that the modem says we're at 7611Kbps but the ASA doesn't report that.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you done a proper speed test by plugging the modem directly into a laptop and running the speed test from there (configuring PPPoE if needed)?  That test usually instantly determines if it is an ISP issue or an internal network issue.

Comment: I tried to do that and failed.  I couldn't get the laptop to go online.  I tried using DHCP, then I tried assigning it one or two of our static IPs, neither worked.  I stopped trying because in doing so, I was keeping our network offline.  I guess I can try again, and maybe call the ISP for support.

Comment: Check the configuration on the Cisco ASA.  If it's set to just a static IP, copy the IP/subnet/gateway settings to the laptop.  If it's set for PPPoE, set that up on the laptop (and probably call Verizon for the password).  You might have to do this after hours to avoid irritating the rest of the staff :)  If the speed test is still low direct to the laptop, yell at verizon until they fix it.  If it's fine, the problem is in your network.  Ideally run a speed test through the ASA just before you disconnect it to compare to.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for a speedtest? The typical speedtest runs over TCP, which will be affected by latency and other factors. The DSL modem is probably doing some sort of test to the device immediately connected on the other side, which will have the lowest possible latency and the fastest overall results.

> We've had this DSL line for years, and it was never this slow.

What factors are you using to determine "it is slow"? Do you run regular speedtests? Are the users complaining?

There are many things that can contribute to the perception of a connection being "slow", including latency, DNS response time, and packet loss (and of course limited bandwidth). In addition to asking your DSL provider, you should look into other possible causes as well, including

1. Has the router been upgraded recently?
2. Have there been any configuration changes? An example might be enhanced inspection for "security".
3. Have the systems that are experiencing the symptoms had an upgrade or configuration change recently?

And more. Hopefully this can get you going in the right direction.

Comment: For speedtest, I'm looking at PRTG/Netflow's reporting of speed, and the sites speedtest.net and speedof.me.  Users are complaining regularly now; when they do, speed tests show speeds below 500kbps.  

The only other system upgrades are regular Microsoft critical/security patches.

We did recently upgrade the Anyconnect package on our Cisco, I'm not sure if firmware or anything else got upgraded too.  And I'm not entirely sure what the ASA is inspecting.  

If the direct modem-laptop test is fine, maybe a call to Cisco could help optimize the router?  We do have a smartnet contract.